# Grails : Spring Security Core Shiro plugin not remembering resource user attempted to access

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using Spring Security Shiro in a Grails 3.3.9 project. Why would the plugin not remember the resource the account holder attempted to access before authenticating?

I would like the user/account holder to be redirected to the resource he or she originally requested.

Example:

```
User requests context/controller/resource/id
```

**context/controller/resource/id** is secured by the plugin. The user logs in. Instead of being directed to `context/controller/resource/id`, instead the user is directed to `/`. How do I make sure the user is directed to the requested resource? What would be causing this effect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you set grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault to true as  it has been done here to enable the behavior you don't want? https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/issues/560

Comment: No, I don't have that set. I just tried setting and still same issue. Thanks

Comment: Is the URL (context/controller/resource/id) being accessed via GET or POST before the user is sent to the login?

Comment: GET, would you like to look at the code base? Thanks